# Python readline() on the Mac

Tags: python, macos, file-io

New to python and trying to learn the ropes of file i/o.

Working with pulling lines from a large (2 million line) file in this format:

```
56fr4
4543d
4343d
hirh3
```

I've been reading that readline() is best because it doesn't pull the whole file into memory.  But when I try to read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) on it, it seems to be Unix only?  And I'm on a Mac.

Can I use readline on the Mac without loading the whole file into memory?  What would the syntax be to simply readline number 3 in the file?  The examples in the docs are a bit over my head.

Edit

Here is the function to return a code:

```
def getCode(i):
    with open("test.txt") as file:
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == i:
                code = # what does it equal?
                break
    return code
```

Comment: Readline is a library for dealing with terminal keyboard input. It has nothing to do with reading files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman See my comment below regarding your confusing file.readline() and the readline module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need `readline`:

```
with open("data.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        # do stuff with line
```

This will read the entire file line-by-line, but not all at once (so you don't need all the memory). If you want to abort reading the file, because you found the line you want, use `break` to terminate the loop. If you know the index of the line you want, use this:

```
with open("data.txt") as file:
    for index, line in enumerate(file):
        if index == 2: # looking for third line (0-based indexes)
            # do stuff with this line
            break # no need to go on
```

Comment: How would I return line three?  Just want to make sure I am understanding the syntax..

Comment: @some1: Updated my answer to show how to find a particular line by number.

Comment: Extremely helpful, thank you very much.  I would have been messing with readline way too long probably.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y, Actually one more question.  How do I grab the code?  Once the index == 2, how do I set the code to a variable?  Editing the post to show my function.

Comment: +1 for iterator objects. http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/bltin-file-objects.html

Comment: If you want to change the starting index to say, 1, you can do: `for index, line in enumerate(file, 1):`

Comment: @some1: `line` contains the text of the line (including the terminal new-line). So you could do `code = line.strip()` - the `strip()` removes the terminal new-line.

Comment: I made the mistake of asking this question in a new submission and got chewed out.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

+1 @ SpaceC0wb0y

You could also do:

```
f = open('filepath')
f.readline() # first line - let it pass
f.readline() # second line - let it pass
third_line = f.readline()
f.close()
```